# Change Calender view in openerp

Tags: odoo

As of now calendar in openerp there is default hourly format from 24 Hrs but i want to change 12 Hrs format for Calendar.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are three type of categories in calendar view.

- Day
- Week
- Month

When you click on Day button your data will bifurcate in 12Hrs manner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to display only 12 hrs ? Or you want the 24 hrs but with a range of 2 hrs ?

if you want the first solution, simply put day_length attribute to your calendar tag with an integer to specify how many hrs you want to display (actually, it only permits to create records on those 12 hrs, it's consided as a "working day length".).

example :

```
<calendar day_length="12" ....... >
<!-- some fields -->
<calendar />
```

Otherwise, i think you have to override default calendar view, but i can't help you to do that.

Regards,

Nonow Dev